# Have a function only use cells in it's range that are >= a date in google docs

Tags: google-sheets, google-docs

I have a list of timestamped data and only want my UNIQUE function to use the data on rows whose date cell is greater than or equal to a set date. So that the set date can be changed and anything from that date onward is used, but any date before then is not used.

My data is fairly simple and looks something like:

```
4/15/2014  Fred  productname  productquantity
4/17/2014  John  productname  productquantity
```

And in another location:

```
StartDate  4/17/2014
```

My UNIQUE function is pulling from both column B and C (Persons name, and product name). The idea is to use the date provided (beside "Start Date") and limit the function to only use data from that date onwards.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

I would use the FILTER function to narrow down the data:

=filter(A:D,A:A>=F3)

Assuming that the value of StartDate is in the cell "F3". (Also assuming that all date types are in the correct date format!)

This will give back only those rows which meets the condition. And then if you would like to add this to UNIQUE, using only the B and C columns, I would write:

=unique(filter(B:C,A:A>=F3))

Hope this helped.